# make png swing to work on most browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a png like

```
<img class="swing" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png" />
```

How can I apply swing effect to it?

I was looking in goolge and found this code

```
@-webkit-keyframes swing {
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; }
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); }   
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes swing {
    20% { -moz-transform: rotate(15deg); }  
    40% { -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -moz-transform: rotate(5deg); }   
    80% { -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg); }  
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes swing {
    20% { -o-transform: rotate(15deg); }    
    40% { -o-transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { -o-transform: rotate(5deg); } 
    80% { -o-transform: rotate(-5deg); }    
    100% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes swing {
    20% { transform: rotate(15deg); }   
    40% { transform: rotate(-10deg); }
    60% { transform: rotate(5deg); }    
    80% { transform: rotate(-5deg); }   
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

.swing {
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
    -moz-transform-origin: top center;
    -o-transform-origin: top center;
    transform-origin: top center;
    -webkit-animation-name: swing;
    -moz-animation-name: swing;
    -o-animation-name: swing;
    animation-name: swing;
}
```

But it may not work? Is there a way to apply swing effect to png and see it on most browsers?

How to apply the effect, [I made a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5v7V/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the animation a duration

```
.swing {
   -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
   -moz-transform-origin: top center;
   -o-transform-origin: top center;
   transform-origin: top center;
   -webkit-animation: swing 2s;
   -moz-animation: swing 2s;
   -o-animation: swing 2s;
   animation: swing 2s;
}
```

Comment: One question, how can I apply this effect but when I hover the image `a:swing
{ 
...
}`  ?

Comment: Your selector would be `a.swing:hover` (or just `.swing:hover`)

Comment: The selector would never be `a.swing:hover`; the long version would be `img.swing:hover`.

Comment: to make it look smoother you can add `ease-in-out` after the duration.  For instance: `animation: swing 2s ease-in-out` http://jsfiddle.net/JXYZn/